# How to get a Device Specific UID using Python in ASE on Android?

Tags: python, android, ase, android-scripting

I am working on am Android Scripting Environment (ASE) script in Python to replicate an iPhone app.

I need a device UID of some sort. My thoughts where a salted MD5 hash of the MAC address or device phone number, but I can't figure out how to access either of those using the Python APIs within ASE.

What can I do to create a UID in Python in ASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer versions of ASE now include a function call to create these identifiers.